# Indian visa for Pakistani National

Tags: india, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national, however my girlfriend is from India we met in third country, now she is back in India, and I want to visit her, can I get the visa for India on basis of meeting girlfriend or should I have to make some other reason to apply.

Comment: What other credible and provable reason could you give? It’s generally best to tell the truth where visa applications are concerned.

Comment: It is especially advisable to be truthful and careful in your visa application to India, given the current political situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pakistani nationals can apply for a [Visitor Visa](https://www.india.org.pk/pages.php?id=132) to visit friends or relatives in India. This includes your girlfriend.

Because Pakistani nationals cannot obtain Tourist Visas, you should apply for a Visitor Visa and explicitly declare that you wish to visit your girlfriend. She will need to send you a [sponsorship certificate](https://www.india.org.pk/pdf/SPONSORSHIP_CERTIFICATE_june12_1.pdf) that you will include with your visa application.

You can find the required documents and visa application process on the [High Commission of India in Islamabad](https://www.india.org.pk/pages.php?id=114) web site.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for detail response. I am currently in the US and will be applying for the Indian visa from here. I guess, the procedure and documents that are required will be same.

Comment: @Touseef The process is different when applying from the USA. See the [Embassy of India in Washington DC](https://www.indianembassyusa.gov.in/pages?id=3&subid=12) web site for the details.